# Extraer información de diccionario - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
{'message': 'success',
 'number': 7,
 'people': [{'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Sergey Ryzhikov'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Kate Rubins'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Sergey Kud-Sverchkov'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Mike Hopkins'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Victor Glover'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Shannon Walker'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Soichi Noguchi'}]}
```

Tengo que determinar la cantidad de *crafts* diferentes que hay dentro de *people*. Evidentemente sé que la respuesta debe ser *1* (puesto que sólo nos aparece la *ISS*, mientras que si en alguno de los casos en vez de *ISS* apareciera *Enterprise*, entonces la respuesta debería ser *2*).

¿Cómo se determina esto?

Comment: `len(set(x['craft'] for x in d['people']))`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, tanto por por la rapidez como por la respuesta. Me funciona perfectamente !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código que escribí hace lo que necesitas!
En él creo un `set` a partir de la sintaxis de la lista comprimida. En los sets no se pueden repetir valores, por lo tanto, al guardar el valor de 'craft' no se guarda repetido. Entonces solo queda medir el largo del set resultante.

```
dic = {'message': 'success',
 'number': 7,
 'people': [{'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Sergey Ryzhikov'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Kate Rubins'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Sergey Kud-Sverchkov'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Mike Hopkins'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Victor Glover'},
  {'craft': 'ISS', 'name': 'Shannon Walker'},
  {'craft': 'Enterprise', 'name': 'Soichi Noguchi'}]}

print(len({persona["craft"] for persona in dic['people']}))
```

Por cierto, @abulafia se me adelantó. No olvides puntuar su comentario (si puedes)!